# grep json value of a key name. (busybox without option -P)

Tags: json, linux, bash

I found tons of threads who discussed "how to grep json values". 
But unfortunately useless for me and all who using grep from busybox (embedded linux). This grep version doesn't have the option "-P" (perl exp). Only "-E" (Extended Regexp) is available.

```
BusyBox v1.20.2 () multi-call binary.

Usage: grep [-HhnlLoqvsriwFE] [-m N] [-A/B/C N] PATTERN/-e PATTERN.../-f FILE [FILE]...

Search for PATTERN in FILEs (or stdin)

        -H      Add 'filename:' prefix
        -h      Do not add 'filename:' prefix
        -n      Add 'line_no:' prefix
        -l      Show only names of files that match
        -L      Show only names of files that don't match
        -c      Show only count of matching lines
        -o      Show only the matching part of line
        -q      Quiet. Return 0 if PATTERN is found, 1 otherwise
        -v      Select non-matching lines
        -s      Suppress open and read errors
        -r      Recurse
        -i      Ignore case
        -w      Match whole words only
        -x      Match whole lines only
        -F      PATTERN is a literal (not regexp)
        -E      PATTERN is an extended regexp
        -m N    Match up to N times per file
        -A N    Print N lines of trailing context
        -B N    Print N lines of leading context
        -C N    Same as '-A N -B N'
        -e PTRN Pattern to match
        -f FILE Read pattern from file
```

I have a json example:

```
{
  "one": "apple",
  "two": "banana"
}
```

Now, I want to extract the value e.g. "apple" from key "one".

```
grep -E '".*?"' file.json
```

Just an example how it should look like.

And btw: How to access groups from regex?

I would be grateful for any help or alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `busybox awk`:

```
busybox awk  -F '[:,]' '/"one"/ {gsub("[[:blank:]]+", "", $2); print $2}'
```

- `-F '[:,]'` sets the field separator as `:` or `,`
- `/"one"/ {gsub("[[:blank:]]+", "", $2); print $2}` macthes if the line contains `"one"`, if so strips off all horizontal whitespace(s) from second field and then printing the field

If you want to strip off the quotes too:

```
busybox awk  -F '[:,]' '/"one"/ {gsub("[[:blank:]\"]+", "", $2); print $2}'
```

---

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.json 
{
  "one": "apple",
  "two": "banana"
}

$ busybox awk  -F '[:,]' '/"one"/ {gsub("[[:blank:]]+", "", $2); print $2}' file.json 
"apple"

$ busybox awk  -F '[:,]' '/"one"/ {gsub("[[:blank:]\"]+", "", $2); print $2}' file.json 
apple
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. A solution without grep. But works like a charm.

Comment: THANK YOU! Took me 2h to find this answer :(

Answer (score 1):

I like simple commands which enhance readability and easy to understand. In your file first we have to remove whitespaces to match the string. For that I usually prefer `sed` command. After that we can use `awk` command to find the match.

```
awk -F: '$1=="one" {print $2}' | sed -r 's/(\t|\s|,)//g' file.json
```

It will return:

```
"apple"
```

**Note: I removed Comma(,) which present at end of line. If you need Comma also as output then refer below command.**

```
awk -F: '$1=="one" {print $2}' | sed -r 's/(\t|\s)//g' file.json
```

It will return:

```
"apple",
```

Answer (score 0):

**awk** solution won't work if a single line json

example:

```
{"one":"apple","two":"banana"}
```

following **sed** will do:

```
busybox cat file.json | sed -n 's/.*"one":\([^}, ]*\).*/\1/p'
```